# How do I use SpecFlow's "Scenarios" keyword?

Tags: specflow

In my feature file, IntelliSense says that there is a keyword called `Scenarios`.  Note that it is *plural*.  I've poured through the [documentation](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/Using-Gherkin-Language-in-SpecFlow) and can't find any references to it.  Can anybody explain what it is for and how it can be used?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That's a synonym to the Examples word used in for different Scenarios using the Scenario Outline construct... Or in plain English; if you use a Scenario Outline you can list the different examples under the keyword "Examples", or under the keyword "Scenarios".

Here is an example:

```
Scenario Outline: eating
  Given there are <start> cucumbers
  When I eat <eat> cucumbers
  Then I should have <left> cucumbers

  Scenarios:
    | start | eat | left |
    |  12   |  5  |  7   |
    |  20   |  5  |  15  |
```

I didn't know that before but it's easy to spot by looking in the [language file](https://github.com/cucumber/gherkin/blob/ead908c194dd79eb57a78c119a7a9cd61f2d6b9c/gherkin-languages.json). Here you'll find all the words in the all the supported languages.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and that link.  The link also showed me what Scenario Template does (the same as Scenario Outline).  Very helpful!

Comment: Hey great - I missed the Scenario Template stuff. In my native language, Swedish, there's loads of strange overloads in Gherkin. You tend to pick up some and stick with them, huh?